# How to extract the field using Gson

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

I am trying to use Gson to extract a field from a Json:

> { "attributes": { "538": { "id": "538", "code": "sabor", "label": "Sabor", "options": [ { "id": "24", "label": "Baunilha", "price": "0", "oldPrice": "0", "products": [ "1376" ] }, { "id": "25", "label": "Chocolate", "price": "0", "oldPrice": "0", "products": [ "1377" ] } ] } } }

What i need is the label field inside the options( in this case, Baunilha and Chocolate).

I tried with the following classes:

> public class Customer implements Serializable{

```
@SerializedName("options")
private Produto options;

public Produto getOptions() {
    return options;
}

public void setEmail(Produto options) {
    this.options = options;
}
```

and

> public class Produto implements Serializable{

```
@SerializedName("label")
private String label;

public String getLabel() {
    return  label;
}

public void setLabel(String label) {
    this.label = label;
}
```

}

> Customer cust = g.fromJson(ja, Customer.class);

But i keep getting null pointer errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the "options" value is not an object consisting of a string, the "options" value is an array of objects. You need to change your definition in Customer to be:

```
class CustomerWrapper {
    @SerializedName("attributes")
    private Map<String, Customer> attributes;
}

class Customer {
    @SerializedName("options")
    private List<Produto> options;
}
```

Comment: Your JSON is a multi nested field that would involve more object nesting. "options" field is embedded in the "538" field which is embedded in the "attributes" field.